# Cannot destructure property 'admins' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: react-redux

I get an error when getting 'admins' data from MongoDB with redux. Follow the code with me and see where the problem.

I can't post a picture of the error so I'm writing it here:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'admins' of '(0 , react_redux__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.useSelector)(...)' as it is undefined.
    at AdminsAdmin (AdminsAdmin.js:21:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
```

AdminsAdmin.js file

```
import { getAdmins } from '../../../redux/actions/authAdminActions';

export default function AdminsAdmin() {
    const { admins } = useSelector((state) => state.admins);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getAdmins());
    }, [dispatch]);

    console.log(admins);
}
```

authAdminActions.js file

```
export const getAdmins = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: START_LOADING });
        const { data } = await api.fetchAdmins();
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL_ADMINS, payload: data });
        dispatch({ type: END_LOADING });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log({ errorGetAdminsAction: err.message });
    }
};
```

api/index.js file

```
import axios from 'axios';

const API = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:5500', headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });

export const fetchAdmins = () => API.get(`/admin/admins`);
```

routes/admin.js file

```
import {getAdmins} from "../controllers/AdminController.js";

router.get("/admins", getAdmins);
```

AdminsController.js file

```
import AdminsModel from "../models/AdminsModel.js";

export const getAdmins = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const admins = await AdminsModel.find();
        console.log("admins", admins);
        res.status(200).json(admins);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ errorGetAdminsController: err.message });
    }
};
```

AdminsReducer.js file

```
import {FETCH_ALL_ADMINS, START_LOADING, END_LOADING} from '../../constants/actionTypes';

const adminReducers = (state = { isLoading: true, admins: [] }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case START_LOADING:
            return { ...state, isLoading: true };
        case END_LOADING:
            return { ...state, isLoading: false };

        case FETCH_ALL_ADMINS:
            return { ...state, admins: action.payload };
        case FETCH_ADMINS_BY_SEARCH:
            return { ...state, admins: action.payload };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export { adminReducers };
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raJ12.png)

Comment: Please check your store.js , and make sure you have given 'admins' correctly on your combined reducer

Comment: I checked and admins are not wrong.